# Python list comprehension Remove duplicates

Tags: python, django

I want unique elements in `hubcode_list`. I can do it by

```
hubcode_alarm_obj = HubAlarm.objects.all()
for obj in hubcode_alarm_obj:
    hubcode = obj.hubcode
    if hubcode not in hubcode_list:
        hubcode_list.append(hubcode)
```

I want to use list comprehension. I'm trying this but it says `hubcode_list` is undefined, which is the correct bug. How can I only add unique elements in `hubcode_list`

```
hubcode_alarm_obj = HubAlarm.objects.all()
hubcode_list = [obj.hubcode for obj in hubcode_alarm_obj if obj.hubcode not in hubcode_list]
```

I can also do it by:-

```
hubcode_list = list(set([obj.hubcode for obj in hubcode_alarm_obj]))
```

But set is again another operation. Can I do it by using `if-statement` in list-comprehension?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: yes in old python versions with a disgusting hack. You should do this with a `set` - even though it's a second "operation", it would be faster than the proposed list comprehension.

Comment: So you prefer the `set` method?

Comment: Is using [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) an option?

Comment: Ohh yeah... I can use distinct as well. Nice suggestion. Thanks. +1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. On the other note, Can I update a column of all the filtered results in one go. Currently I do like this. `reminder_obj = HubAlarm.objects.filter(a = b)  for obj in reminder_obj:   obj.repeat = 'False'   obj.save() `

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using django, let the database do the filtering for you. It will be (by far) the fastest option:

```
objects = HubAlarm.objects.exclude(hubcode__in=hubcode_list)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) for more.

Comment: Thanks for it.I've another question. 
Can I update a column of all the filtered results in one go. Currently I do like this.
`reminder_obj = HubAlarm.objects.filter(a = b)
 for obj in reminder_obj:
  obj.repeat = 'False'
  obj.save()`

Comment: Sure, see [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#update).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is no. List comprehension creates a completely new list all at one shot, so you can't check to see if something exists:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 3, 3, 4]
>>> new = [item for item in lst if item not in new]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'new' is not defined
>>>
```

Therefore, the preferred one-liner is to use `list(set(...))`.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 3, 3, 4]
>>> list(set(lst))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

However, in a list of lists, this would not work:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 5], [6, 7]]
>>> list(set(lst))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
```

In that case, use the standard `for` loop and `.append()`.