# How to remove adjacent duplicate elements in a list using list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a way to use list comprehensions in python to filter **adjacent** duplicates from a list?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
>>> xs = [1,2,2,3]
>>> print added.reAdj(xs)
[1,2,3]
```

A search through SE revealed an [earlier inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881352/python-list-comprehension-remove-duplicates) asking a *similar* but slightly different question: whether all duplicates could be removed from a list, **but not explicitly asking for solutions involving list comprehensions**. The motivation for using list comprehensions specifically follows a recognition of [their advantages over traditional for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341775/what-is-the-advantage-of-a-list-comprehension-over-a-for-loop).  Users suggested the use of the set() function or standard looping as such:

```
result = []
most_recent_elem = None
for e in xs:
    if e != most_recent_elem:
        result.append(e)
        most_recent_elem = e
```

The `set()` suggestion fails to meet the task in that non-adjacent duplicates are removed, while the loop is effective but verbose.

It seems a means for safely referencing the next element in a list comprehension as follows is needed.

```
[x for x in xs if x != **x.next()**]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this mean even `[1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6] --> [1,2,3,4,5,6]` ?

Comment: @IronFist, you understand correctly. That's the desired result.

Comment: @Achampion. Thanks for the link, but as far as I can tell, the poster doesn't ask specifically for an answer involving list comprehensions. My original question post included a loop solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with solution suggested by @AChampion:

```
xs = [1,2,2,2,1,1]
In [115]: [n for i, n in enumerate(xs) if i==0 or n != xs[i-1]]
Out[115]: [1, 2, 1]
```

That list comprehension return item if it's first or for the following if it's not equal to previous. It'll work due to lazy evaluations of `if` statement.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov. Please update when you make progress. Its unfortunate that the case that Stefan Pochmann brought up doesn't work because your solution otherwise is very elegant IMO.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov - **Please**, please, please incorporate AChampion's suggested fix into your answer. This is so much better than an inscrutable call to some inscrutable function in `itertools` whose documentation is in turn inscrutable.

Comment: @DavidHammen `groupby` is easy and perfectly alright, you shouldn't blame it for your own deficiency.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov - And now you get a minus one. As everyone knows,`xs[-1]` refers to the last element of an array in python. If you do not correct for this, your answer is flat out wrong.

Comment: Seems as if the bug is clear. I'll accept this answer pending any additional problems people suggest over the next few hours.

Answer (score 30):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [key for key, grp in itertools.groupby([1, 2, 2, 3])]
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

`itertools.groupby` returns an iterator. By iterating it, you will get a key, group pairs. (`key` will be a item if no `key` function is specified, otherwise the return value of the `key` function). `group` is an iterator which will yields items grouped by applying `key` function (if not specified, same values will be grouped)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> it = itertools.groupby([1, 2, 2, 3])
>>> it
<itertools.groupby object at 0x7feec0863048>
>>> for key, grp in it:
...     print(key)
...     print(grp)
... 
1
<itertools._grouper object at 0x7feec0828ac8>
2
<itertools._grouper object at 0x7feec0828b00>
3
<itertools._grouper object at 0x7feec0828ac8>
>>> it = itertools.groupby([1, 2, 2, 3])
>>> for key, grp in it:
...     print(list(grp))
... 
[1]
[2, 2]
[3]
```

Above solution, I used only `key` because the question does not care how many items are adjacent.

Comment: It's so strange to see `groupby` used without a sorted input, but I guess this is actually appropriate in this particular use case.

Comment: Same here it confused me at first

Comment: @wim the desire to be able to do this sort of thing is part of why `groupby` is designed the way it is.

Answer (score 5):

Using pairwise from the itertools recipes (with zip_longest) gives you an easy way of checking the next element:

```
import itertools as it

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = it.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return it.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=object())   # izip_longest for Py2

>>> xs = [1,2,2,3]
>>> [x for x, y in pairwise(xs) if x != y]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> xs = [1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6]
>>> [x for x, y in pairwise(xs) if x != y]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Slight nitpick: It removes trailing `None` values.

Comment: Noted: but not an issue with a list of ints. And can be avoided with adding a `fillvalue` to `zip_longest`, fixed!

Answer (score 4):

You could use a less verbose loop solution:

```
>>> result = xs[:1]
>>> for e in xs:
        if e != result[-1]:
            result.append(e)
```

Or:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for e in xs:
        if e not in result[-1:]:
            result.append(e)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
>>> l = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,3,3,5,5,7,8,8,8,9,1,2,3,3,3,10,10]
>>> 
>>> o = []
>>> p = None
>>> for n in l:
        if n == p:
            continue
        o.append(n)
        p = n    

>>> o
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 10]
```

Apparently, above solution is more verbose than OP's, so here is an alternative to that using [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.zip_longest) from `itertools` module:

```
>>> l
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10]
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> o = [p for p,n in zip_longest(l,l[1:]) if p != n] #By default fillvalue=None
>>> o
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 10]
```

Comment: It works but it's exactly the same logic as the OP, except being slightly more verbose.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh .. yep...I forgot about that point *verbosity*

Comment: Updated .. using `zip_longest`