# Concise a for loop (x for x in ...) in python

Tags: python

I am trying to concise the following simple loop

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
for x in set(a):
    a.remove(x)
```

This is working well but I need to know if it is possible to apply the concise for loop like that

```
a = [x for x in set(a):a.remove(x)]
```

My desire output is to get or list the duplicates only and get list of them, so the desired output is `[1,2,5]`

The code is working well

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]

for x in set(a):
    a.remove(x)

print(list(set(a)))
```

My target is not the code but to concise the loop in the loop. I need to learn this trick.

** Found a simple and effective solution:

```
print(list(set([x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1])))
```

Comment: `set(a)` will remove duplicates. This results in `{1, 2, 5}`. You are going to iterate thru this and remove the values. This results in a subset. Is that what you want?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean (forgive me as I am a beginner). I need to know the structure of using `x for x in ...` . Would I use another variable instead of `a` variable?

Comment: @JoeFerndz It won't delete everything. It will just remove the first occurrence of each one number in the list.

Comment: @ValeriiBoldakov, you my bad. I edited my comment. Yes, OP is looking to just delete the first occurrences of the value from the set.

Comment: @YasserKhalil, are you trying to remove duplicates? What is your desired output?

Comment: I am seeking to use such line after loop `print(list(set(a)))` to list the duplicates. The problem is not in the code, I need to learn how to concise the loop.

Comment: So you are looking to get `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]` as the answer?

Comment: @JoeFerndz Yes exactly.

Comment: So you are looking to get the set of a. Why do you need to do list comprehension when python already provides you the option of `set(a)`. If it is for learning purpose, then ok.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881352/python-list-comprehension-remove-duplicates

Comment: @Steve, totally with you. I think the question is not clear at all. Anyway, I wrote up a list comprehension that gives the result of `list(set(a))` which may be what the ask was.

Comment: @YasserKhalil - Can you PLEASE put the desired result in your question?  This is all very confusing the way it is now.  It seems that you're saying above in the comments that  `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]` is the right answer.  But in the question itself, you seems to say that what you want is the same result given by your `for` loop, which is `[2, 1, 5, 5, 5]`, but just done in a more concise way.  So which is it?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## find dups in a list

```
print ([c for i,c in enumerate(a) if a.count(c) > 1 and i==a.index(c)])
```

The output of this will be:

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

## alternate for set(a)

Here's the list comprehension to create the same result as

```
print(list(set(a)))
```

This can be achieved by doing the following:

```
print([c for i,c in enumerate(a) if i==a.index(c)])
```

Here I am checking if the element `c` is the first time we encountered (index is `i`) and if yes, then add to list else ignore.

The output of both these will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

While the output is the same, I would strongly recommend using the first method than doing a for loop and checking for index. The cost is too high to do this compared to `list(set(a))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the desired output to list the duplicates `[1,2,5]`

Comment: Let me writeup the code to give you the duplicates. I dont think that's too complicated.

Comment: I have updated the question to make the issue clearer.

Comment: @YasserKhalil, see if this solved your problem. You just need to check if count of `c` is more than 1.

Answer (score 2):

**Original question**

```
a = a if not all([a.remove(i) for i in set(a) ]) else []
print(a)
```

---

As suggested by Copperfield, the following also works:

```
a = any(a.remove(i) for i in set(a) ) or a
```

**Updated question**

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]

print([k for k, v in Counter(a).items() if v > 1])
```

Comment: you can also use `or` for that: `a = all([a.remove(i) for i in set(a) ]) or a`

Comment: `any` works too, and you don't need to make a temporary list with it: `a = any(a.remove(i) for i in set(a) ) or a`

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I tried your code and tried to print like that `print(set(a))` I got `{1, 2, 5}`. Is it possible to get it as a list `[1, 2, 5]`?

Comment: @YasserKhalil You got a ```set``` type because you converted to it in the first place by calling ```set(..)``` constructor. Try print with ```print(a)``` because ```a``` is already a list type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. my target is to get a list of duplicates only.

Comment: @YasserKhalil If you want ```[1, 2, 5]``` as your final output, you can use ```list(...)``` after ```set(...)``` as follows: ```print(list(set(a)))```.

Comment: Yes that is right and I already used it. But what if I need more concise in one line ..? I mean like that `print(list(set([a.remove(x) for x in set(a)])))`

Comment: I also found this line that is very simple and effective `print(list(set([x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1])))`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```py
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
[a.remove(x) for x in set(a)]
print(a)
```

`a` will have the same items as after your `for` loop.

You can read more about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: this will result in `[None, None, None, None, None]` This is not what the OP wants

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used this line at the end `print(list(set(a)))` and it works well.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I'm not doing `a = [a.remove(x) for x in set(a)]`. So no, `a` will be `[2, 1, 5, 5, 5]`. Just like after OP's `for` loop.

Comment: `list(set(a))` is not the same as `[a.remove(x) for x in set(a)]`. The outputs will be different.

Comment: @JoeFerndz, sure thing it will be different. OP's question is for list comprehension instead of the mentioned `for` loop. So I'm providing the answer to the asked question.

Comment: @ValeriiBoldakov, works. I am trying to figure out a list comprehension that can remove duplicates.

Comment: This gives `[2, 1, 5, 5, 5]`.  How is that right?  That doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking for.  I don't get the upvotes.

Comment: @Steve OP is asking to "Concise a for loop". Not to delete duplicates. OP wants a short substitution for the `for` loop. And I'm answering exactly that question and not something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I tried the code I got `{1, 2, 5}` after this line `print(set(a))`. How can I make it as  a list`[1, 2, 5]`?

Comment: @YasserKhalil just wrap it with `list`. Like `print(list(set(a)))`.

Comment: Is it possible to make it in one line like that `print(list(set([a.remove(x) for x in set(a)])))` but this returns None.